# Is there any way to reference an subobject's x position against it's x position on the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently working on an actionscript game, and am trying to set stage boundaries; however, the player object is a subobject of a stage object; and when referencing player.x, I'm getting it's x position within the level object itself. In essence, what I'm trying to do is;

```
if (player.x < stage.x.0) {
player.x = stage.x.0
}
```

Is there any easy way to do this, or should I simply make sure the player object is always on the stage, rather than as a subobject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [localToGlobal()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29) method to convert a Point (flash.geom.Point) from one object's coordinates to stage coordinates. Either by asking subobject to convert the player's location:

```
var playerPosition:Point = new Point(subobject.player.x, subobject.player.y);
var playerPositionOnStage:Point = subobject.localToGlobal(playerPosition);
```

Or, because a new Point is at 0, 0 by default, by asking the player object itself to convert that to global coordinates:

```
var playerPositionOnStage:Point = subobject.player.localToGlobal(new Point());
```